# cray CC wrapper cmake find_package blas

Tags: cmake, blas, cray

I just created a three line CMakeLists.txt as follows under a test directory with no files under it. I tried export lib path etc and none of the basic tricks worked. How to make this work?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test CXX)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
```

and ran this as and got the following error.

```
ramki@hostname:~/temp>CC=CC CXX=CC cmake ../nmflibrary/test/
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Cray Programming Environment 2.5.13 CXX
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/cray/craype/2.5.13/bin/CC
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/cray/craype/2.5.13/bin/CC -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at /autofs/nccs-svm1_sw/titan/.swci/0-login/opt/spack/20170612/linux-suse_linux11-x86_64/gcc-4.3.4/cmake-3.9.0-owxiriblogovogl5zbrg45ulm3ln34cx/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:699 (message):
  A required library with BLAS API not found.  Please specify library
  location.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/ccs/home/ramki/temp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/ccs/home/ramki/temp/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

How to make find_package with blas required work on cray wrappers?

Answer (score 1):

Cray compilers implicitly link the BLAS and LAPACK libraries, so they are normally not given on the command line. The capability to detect this situation was [added](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2312) to CMake 3.13.0 for BLAS and will be [added](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/3451) to CMake 3.16.0 for LAPACK.

So if you are fine with BLAS only, just [download](https://cmake.org/download/) a newer CMake binary tarball.